# <Python - Kivy > GridLayout rendering a single Tile

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following python classes:

```
import os

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

from crawler.settings import ASSETS_DIR


class Map(GridLayout):
    SIZE = 5

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Map, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for _ in range(0, self.SIZE**2):
            self.add_widget(Tile())


class Tile(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Image(source=os.path.join(ASSETS_DIR, 'images/chest.gif')))
```

And the following kv language definition:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Map>:
    size: self.parent.size

<Tile>:
    size: 20, 20
```

This only renders 1 chest (actually the loop runs ok, so maybe they're stacked?):
[image]
While if I change the Tile class for some of the out-of-the-box Widgets like a Button:

```
class Map(GridLayout):
SIZE = 5

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Map, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    for _ in range(0, self.SIZE**2):
        self.add_widget(Button(text=str(_)))
```

It displays the correct result:
[image]

What am I missing in my Tile class to make this work? I think that's where  the problem is, but I couldn't find it so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Tile(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Image(source=os.path.join(ASSETS_DIR, 'images/chest.gif')))
```

Each Tile is a Widget *containing* an Image, but Widget isn't a layout class so the Image just has the default pos of `(0, 0)` and size of `(100, 100)`.

You could instead make the Tile *be* the Image, or replace Widget with a layout like BoxLayout (this latter choice will be less efficient unless you need the extra layout behaviour).

Comment: That actually makes sense, let me try it